# In Shiny, the submit button isn't running

Tags: r, user-interface, shiny, shiny-server, shinyapps

I wrote a R script (MAIN.R) that converts PDF tables to CSV. When I run MAIN.R as an individual file, it functions well. I've tried it many times.

Currently, I'm working on a R shiny app that uses "MAIN.R" as a source and takes a pdf file as input. When I push the submit button, the output should appear in the MAIN panel. Unfortunately, the submit button does not function as intended.

May anyone please assist me with this, as I am new to Shiny?

**UI.R**

```
shinyUI(fluidPage(
  titlePanel("DATASET CONVERSION"),
  
  sidebarLayout(
    fileInput("filein", label = h2("Select a file to convert.")),
    submitButton("Submit")
  ),
  mainPanel(
    tableOutput("Dataset")
  )
)
)
```

**Server.R**

```
source("MAIN.R")
shinyServer(function(input, output) {
  
  outputdf <-  reactive({ input$filein   
  })    
  output$Dataset <- renderTable({ 
    outputdf()
  })
})
```

Comment: Can you include the `MAIN.R` file to make a MRE? Thanks! How is `outputdf()` defined? I guess something goes wrong when sourcing the function. Please also see that `submitButton` is [deprecated](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/submitButton.html)

Comment: @starja, it isn't *deprecated*, it is *"generally discouraged in favor of the more versatile `actionButton()`"* (though the sentiment remains).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Submit button is not currently linked to anything, so it will not do anything. If I am reading the code right, you are just taking the input dataset and storing it as the output of outputdf. Your output$Dataset then just picks up that outputdf and displays it as-is, without any work being done on it.

You use an action button like so:

```
## In UI.R
actionButton("execute", "Execute the Main Function")

## In Server.R
observeEvent(input$execute, {
    ## Do stuff here
  })
```

Note that the actionButton has two parameters, inputID (which is how you refer to it) and text to display on top. For example, with input$filein, 'filein' is the inputID.

In Server.R, observeEvent won't do anything until it detects a change in input$execute, which happens when someone clicks the button. That is where you put your code to do stuff.

Now, in output$Dataset, you need to access the results of whatever you did in that observeEvent. One way to do that is to use a reactiveValue. This is just like a reactive, but instead of a function, it stores a data element. Initialize it as an empty dataframe, and then update it in the observeEvent. Something like this:

```
## In Server.R
treated_output <- reactiveValue(data.frame())

observeEvent(input$execute, {
    ## Run the function on the file
    updated <- main_function(input$filein)
    
    # Update your reactiveValue
    treated_output(updated)
  })

output$Dataset <- renderTable({ 
    treated_output()
  })
```

Does this make sense?

Comment: As far as I understand the [documentation](https://shiny.rstudio.com/reference/shiny/1.6.0/submitButton.html), `submitButton` stands on its own and all reactives won't update until it is pressed; but in general your solution with an `actionButton` is better

Comment: Yes, it goes well, @Aqeel Padaria. Thank you so much.